# How to authenticate in Remedy using Java

Tags: java, remedy

I need to authenticate myself in Remedy. I'm following the documentation, but I still getting some errors.
https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-17514

This is my code:

```
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARException;
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser;

public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ARServerUser ctx = new ARServerUser();
        ctx.setServer("127.0.0.1");
        ctx.setUser("myusername");
        ctx.setPassword("mypassword");
        ctx.setPort(8080);

        try {
            ctx.verifyUser();
        } catch (ARException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm receiving this error:
`ERROR (91): RPC call failed; 127.0.0.1:8080 can not receive ONC/RPC data`

How can I fix that? I need to set the instance, like `127.0.0.1/arsys`. My Remedy instance is arsys.

I can authenticate using the browser: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/arsys`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your midtier on the same server as your AR server?

if not, then You need to set the IP of your AR server instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that you are able to authenticate using http://127.0.0.1:8080/arsys via browser, it means that 8080 is being used by web server and AR Server can't use the same. Please provide your port number(where your AR Server is listening) in setPort(). Also try to make sure that your hostname/ip address is reachable from the machine where you are executing your program.

Answer (score -1):

The `setServer` parameter expects the name of the ARS server, not the IP address. Here is the matching constructor signature:

```
ARServerUser(java.lang.String user, java.lang.String password, java.lang.String locale, java.lang.String serverName, int serverPort)
```

**References**

- [com.remedy.arsys.api.ARServerUser](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/7814)
- [How to authenticate in Remedy using Java](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/105386)